# Check against two separate array values and grabbing the smallest one to insert into a new array the CW new array values

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working with Arrays and conditionals statements, little lost right now and was hoping for some input.

So, I created two Arrays

```
int[] one = new int[] { 
    4160414, 6610574, 2864453, 9352227, -4750937, -3132620, 2208017,  
    -2226227, -8415856, -9834062, -3401569, 7581671, 8068562, 7520435,  
    -9277044, -7821114, -3095212, 966785, 6873349, -8441152, -7015683, 
    -6588326, -282013, 4051534, 9930123, -3093234 };

int[] two = new int[] { 
    1099626, 6083415, 8083888, -8210392, 2665304, -8710738, -8708241, 
    8859200, -1255323, 5604634, 2921294, -7260228, 7261646, 1137004, 
    5805162, 4883369, 8789460, 9769240, 319012, -7877588, -1573772, 
    5192333, 1185446, 1302131, 4217472, -3471445};
```

My next step what i was thinking is i am going to have to loop through each array

```
for (int i = 0; i < one.Length; i++)
{
    int xValue = one[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < two.Length; j++)
    {
        int yValue = two[j];
    }
}
```

Now that i have the index of each Array i need to check wether the index of xValue is less than the index of yValue

```
if (xValue < yValue)
{
   // dO SOMETHING HERE
}
if (yValue < xValue)
{
  // Do Something HERE
}
```

Where i am getting confused at, is with C# from my understanding you can not push new values into an Array, it needs to be a new instance of the array and copy?

So i tried doing

```
if (xValue < yValue)
{
  Array.Copy(one, x, 13);
}
if (yValue < xValue)
{
 Array.Copy(two, x, 13)
}
```

Both Arrays have 26 values, so a new array of 13 would need to be created to insert the checked value, but Array.Copy seems to not be working getting an array out of bounds check lower bounds.

I'm just confused on checking the values of both arrays at their index, then grabbing the smallest value of the checked values then taking that small value and inserting it into a new array, then use a foreach-loop to iterate over it and print the values to the console. *FacePalm*

Comment: So you have two arrays with 26 items each, and you want a single array with 13? Can you explain more about the logic (ideally with some worked examples, or a diagram)? At the moment it seems like you should end up with a 26 item array containing the smallest values when comparing the same index in both arrays.

Comment: Yes your right i worded that wrong, i should end up with a new array of 26 of the smallest numbers in both arrays

So if i am comparing ArrayOne and the first value is 2 and then the second array is checked and that value is 3, then value 2 will be grabbed and inserted into a new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DOTNET/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2) to achieve this:

```
int[] smallest = one.Zip(two, (o, t) => Math.Min(o,t)).ToArray();
```

Essentially, `Zip` will provide both items to the lambda expression, allowing you to combine them how you see fit. In this case, we just choose the minimum and return it.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/WFJWA50785)

Comment: I never find a use for zip! +1

Comment: I love this, thank you for sharing this with me! appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to define the *size* of the new array when you declare it. Make it the same size as `one`. Then add the smallest item from `one` or `two` on each iteration by comparing the items in each array at index `i`.

```
int[] smallest = new int[one.Length]; 

for (int i = 0; i < one.Length; i++)
{
    if (one[i] < two[i])
    {
        smallest[i] = one[i];
    }
    else 
    {
        smallest[i] = two[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with me! makes a lot more sense now